# Python Uni code For Emojis scraped from twitter tweet with different character length

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I am trying to **scrape** some tweets from Twitter and some of the tweets have emojis with a unicode **\u1f973**, so python interprets it as **\u1f97** convert it to the corresponding character and point **3** as it is. Which seems perfectly fine.
But, the actual value of this code should be **\U0001f973**, which will give me the exact emoji.
I can not use **.replace** function on it.

My string is encode as utf-8

I also know that whenever the code starts with **\u1f**, i need to replace it.
There is no code to show. But if some one wants to test it.
Try this string

```
X = " Hello World \u1f973"
```

it will print

```
Hello World ᾗ3
```

What i want is

```
X = X.replace("\u","\U000")

X = Hello World \U0001f973
```

The twitter problematic emojis are **.svg** files which provide this type of unicode with 5 bit length. Rest all the emojis with **\uxxxx** normal unicode length codes are working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better answer - but this sample 'oh so ugly' code does the trick (you might have to do a zfill within the replace() to pad if the unicode strings are various character lengths other than 5 byte length):

```
'Convert my emoji \u1f973'.encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf-8').replace('\\u', '\\U000').encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape')
```

'Convert my emoji '

Comment: Thank you very much. It will do my work :)